# How to add cell user's password to database with the migration of Laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, passwords, migration

Can't find docs how to add cell user's password to database with the migration of Laravel framework?

Doing like in official documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#creating-a-migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in the textbook https://leanpub.com/codebright (page №250):

```
$table->string('password', 60);
```